# Naming standards for C unions

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I sometime use unions to access the same type of data differently. For example this union:

```
typedef union {
   int64 word;
   int32 array[2];
   struct {
      field4:16;
      field3:16;
      field2:28;
      field1:4;
   } bit;
} my_type;
```

Is this solution consensually correct and is there any standards for the names I used (word, array, bit)?

The bad point with this solution is the cumbersome notation I got:

```
   my_type data;
   data.bit.field1 = 0xA;
   for(i=0;i<sizeof(my_t);i++)
      data.array[i]++;
```

Comment: name *_t* is reserved, don't use it.

Comment: @2501 By what it is reserved? How can I tell that it is a type not a variable?

Comment: At least in some degree: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356626/c-type-naming-conventions-t-or-allcaps

Comment: @coin The POSIX standard reserves all type names ending in _t for itself. This makes it possible for POSIX to introduce new types (with names ending in _t) without breaking existing code.

Comment: Note: Field widths greater than the width of `int/unsigned` are not 100% portable.  Since `int` must only be at least 16 bits, `28` may be a concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some compilers allow to omit the name of struct in a union. You can try to define your type as this:

```
typedef union {
   int64 word;
   int32 array[2];
   struct {
      field4:16;
      field3:16;
      field2:28;
      field1:4;
   } bit;
} my_type;
```

This allows to access the bit members a bit easier:

```
my_type data;
data.field1 = 0xA;
```

But unfortunately this is compiler and compiler options dependent. *Edit:* The C11 Standard [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1494.pdf) describes this as anonymous struct.

Comment: This feature was integrated to the standard with C11. It is called anonymous structure and union member, respectively.